# Import messages with gmail api, apply filters and redirect it

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I try to import message via the gmail API https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/import

Filters was correctly applied but the messages wastn redirected.

Any tips to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you check it in [try it](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/import#try-it) section as well? What was the output?

Comment: yes, output was a message_id and the message is correctly created on my inbox